# Installing kerberos module not through pip

Tags: python, pip, kerberos

Is there an alternative to installing the kerberos module that is not through pip as that is giving me insurmountable issues.

Comment: What are the issues you are facing with `pip`?

Comment: I'd rather fix pip then find a workaround. Pip is essential! What is the output to: `pip install kerberos`?

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from here: https://pypi.org/project/kerberos/#files

unzip the file and run `python setup.py build`